# Remove "npm update check failed" message at log on

Tags: npm

I did a bunch of commands weeks ago that caused the following message to appear every time I access iTerm:

```
                  npm update check failed                     
            Try running with sudo or get access               
           to the local update config store via              
sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /folder/folder/.config
```

How do I remove this message? And anything else it could have dumped in my computer?

It's a persistent message at log on. Unfortunately, I do not know what commands triggered this. And `.bash_history` file didn't help me find which command caused this.

Comment: check the group of your project

Comment: I couldn't figure out what was causing the issue so I ended up removing NPM and all the node modules folders. I am assuming you meant look through the modules folder. After removing it completely the message no longer appears.

Comment: I thought may be the group of that project has been changed. I assume that's cause the issues

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I solved it by running the following command in the iterm2 application.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /folder/folder/.config
```

and restarted the iterm2 application.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the `configstore` folder under the corresponding folder. And running the project again will regenerate the folder without reporting an error.

Answer (score -1):

Run the command as superuser by starting the command with "sudo"

If you like to update your packages listed in your local package.json [npm auto update](https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-updater) package.

Comment: Been some time now, so I cannot share more, by way of a screenshot. The issue is the appreance of the message as a header to the console. So everytime I open iTerm this message is above everything as I run commands for an alternative project. And my inability to determine what program/series of commands triggered such a notice. I was trying to avoid removing npm and re-installing it to rid the message. Hope that made sense!

Comment: sudo npm update      -                                                                                    
run the  command to update your package.json library that will compare the version of the npm repo and your local npm packages.                   add -g for global "npm update" that updates your global packages referring current package.json file where you are running this command

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:
npm install asdf

Comment: "A tiny static web server" — how is this relevant to anything?